# git checkout fail because of new submodule

Tags: git, git-branch

While on development branch I am trying to do:

```
git checkout master
```

And getting the message:

> error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten
>   by checkout:

And it points me to a directory.

The problem is that I made this directory to be submodule. But its not a submodule in master, so it tells me that those files will be override and aborting the checkout.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Should you make new a branch as your submodule. For create new branch:

```
git checkout -b nameofyoubranchoryoursubmodule
```